# Curious Case of $\int \vert x^n \vert dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across a question on integrals, it said if **$n$ is an odd positive integer**, then below integral should be equal to $$\int \vert x^n \vert dx$$

four options were given

$$(a) \biggr\vert \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \biggr\vert   $$
$$(b)  \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}    $$
$$(c)  \frac{\vert x^{n} \vert x}{n+1}    $$
$$ (d) \text{None of these}$$

The answer was given as $(c)$ but I think the answer should be $(b)$ because the answer will have a positive value for $x$ so having $\vert x^n \vert$ should not be necessary.

What do you guys think? Does $n$ being even or odd positive integer makes a difference here? Will deeply appreciate the input on this.

Regards

Sid

Comment: The derivative of (b) is $x^n\ne|x^n|$ when $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n is odd then $$|x^n| =
\begin{cases}
x^n,  & \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
-x^n, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}$$so $$\int|x^n|dx= \begin{cases}
\int x^ndx,  & \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
\int-x^ndx, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}= \begin{cases}
\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1},  & \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}+C$$
$$= \frac{x}{n+1}\begin{cases}
x^n,  & \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
-x^n, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}+C=\frac{x|x^n|}{n+1}+C$$
Then the correct answer is c).

Answer (score 1):

If the integrand has to pass through the origin it'll be odd, so (c) is right. The other options don't have the right derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Ponder the case of $n=1$.

(b) $\left(\dfrac{x^2}2\right)'=x\color{red}{\ne |x|}$, while

(c) $\left(\dfrac{x|x|}2\right)'=\dfrac{|x|+x\text{ sgn}(x)}2= |x|$.

The antiderivative of an even function is an odd function.

---

Now with $n=2$,

(b) $\left(\dfrac{x^3}3\right)'=x^2=|x|^2$, while

(c) $\left(\dfrac{x^2|x|}3\right)'=\dfrac{2x|x|+x^2\text{ sgn}(x)}3=x|x|\color{red}{\ne x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

We seem to have the integral being $0$ when $x=0$, and the potential answers are all the same when $x > 0$ so, since the integrand is positive, the integral will then be negative when $x$ is negative. (c) is the only example which achieves this.  In particular

- when $x$ is negative and $n$ is even, you have $$\int \vert x^n \vert dx = \int  x^n  dx = -\biggr\vert \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \biggr\vert= \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}= \frac{\vert x^{n} \vert x}{n+1}$$
- when $x$ is negative and $n$ is odd, you have  $$\int \vert x^n \vert dx = -\int  x^n  dx = -\biggr\vert \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \biggr\vert= -\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}= \frac{\vert x^{n} \vert x}{n+1}$$